# How to extract only one file from war file?

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml, unzip

I am working on a shell command for Ansible in Linux, I have a
*.war* file, and I need only *tasks.properties* file from it. I tried the below, but it extracts the parent directory folder *WEB-INF*, so, I get *WEB-INF/sub/test.properties* extracted, when I just need the *test.properties* outside

```
unzip test.war "*test.properties*"
```

I also tried

```
jar xf test.war test.properties
```

This also extracted the main folder, and *WEB-INF/sub/test.properties*.

When I `ls`, I just want *test.properties* to appear in the location where I am running this, any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-j` flag is exactly what you need:

```
unzip -j test.war "*test.properties*"
```

From [the docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip):

> -j
>
> junk paths. The archive's directory structure is not recreated; all
> files are deposited in the extraction directory (by default, the
> current one).

Comment: This worked, thanks a bunch :) :)